# How to put multiple files using sftp

Tags: scripting, sftp

Need your help in putting multiple files in the server.
I have created a script but it is not putting all the files

```
cd /buffer/miscellaneous/new/
cd $(ls -t | head -n 1)
latest=$(find -mmin -60 | cut -d'/' -f2 | tail -n +2 | tr '\n' '\t')
/usr/local/bin/sshpass -p password sftp -oBatchMode=no adris@XX.XXX.XXX.XX:/folder1 << 1
mput $latest*
bye
```

For this command

```
find -mmin -60 | cut -d'/' -f2 | tail -n +2 | tr '\n' '\t'
```

Output is 2 csv files:

```
cgi_20111210_235524.csv cgi_20203127_125504.csv
```

Now the issue is `mput` is putting only the first file and not putting the other files.

The output of the find command is as follows

```
find -mmin -60
.
./cgi_20110911_135504.csv
./cgi_20111210_235524.csv
./cgi_20203127_125504.csv
```

Comment: If `$latest` is a space-delimited string with two filenames in it, why do you add `*` at the end of the string when you use it with `mput`?  You also seem to have missed the termination of the here-document (should be a lone `1` on a line after `bye` since you started the redirection with `<<1`).

Comment: even if i remove the * still output remains the same  this is what i get sftp> mput cgi_20111210_235524.csv      cgi_20203127_125504.csv
Uploading cgi_20111210_235524.csv to /adris/cgi_20203127_125504.csv
sftp> bye

Comment: Your commands might not work as expected if you have files in subdirectories. Instead of combining the `find` output to a space-delimited string you could create multi-line input for `sftp`. To propose alternative commands it would help to see the output of `find -mmin -60`. Please [edit] your question to add information.

Comment: @Bodo : added the info of find command.

Comment: I assume `cut -d'/' -f2` is to remove `./` and `tail -n +2` to skip the `.` line, right?

Comment: @Bodo Yes! that's right

Comment: @Bodo The thing is it is not sure how many files i will get in 60 mins it can be 1 file or 10 files or no files at all. So that is why i am using find command

Comment: Here the find with awk: `find . -type f -mmin 60 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="^./"}{printf $2"\t"}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `cut -d'/' -f2` to skip the line `.` in the `find` output can be omitted by adding `-type f` to find only files, not directories.

The command `cut -d'/' -f2` will not result in the file name if there are files in subdirectories, also the command for `sftp` would not work in this case. So I suggest to limit the depth for `find`.

I suggest to create separate commands for `sftp` from the file names printed by `find` and pipe this into your `sftp` command.

```
{ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -60| cut -d'/' -f2 | sed 's/^/put /' ; echo bye ; } | /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p password sftp -oBatchMode=no adris@XX.XXX.XXX.XX:/folder1
```

To see what commands are created for `sftp` you can omit the part `| /usr/local/bin/sshpass`...

**Edit**

To log the file names you can insert something like `tee logfile` into the pipe after the `find` or `cut` command. If you want to append to an existing logfile instead of overwriting it, use `tee -a logfile`

Example:

```
{ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -60 | cut -d'/' -f2 | tee logfile | sed 's/^/put /' ; echo bye ; } | /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p password sftp -oBatchMode=no adris@XX.XXX.XXX.XX:/folder1
```

Comment: Thank you @Bodo works as expected :)

Comment: I want to do some modification in the command. I also want to make a log file in which the filename of all the files being transferred in the command are written in the file.            { find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -60| cut -d'/' -f2 | sed 's/^/put /' ; echo bye ; } | /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p password sftp -oBatchMode=no adris@XX.XXX.XXX.XX:/folder1

Comment: @RichaMohan Do you want to have the output of the `find` command (or after the `cut` command) into a file?

Comment: Thanks I used tee command and it worked well :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure your `sftp` version offers the `mput` command? It is not listed in any `sftp` man page I searched recently; I guess they might accept it for back compatibilty reasons as an "alias" for the `put` command, which in turn can transfer multiple files by itself. `man sftp`:

> **put** [-afPpr] **local-path** **[remote-path]**
>
> Upload local-path and store it on the remote machine.  If the remote path name is not specified, it is given the same name it
>   has on the local machine.  local-path may contain glob(7) characters
>   and may match multiple files.

With two parameters, (`m`)`put` uses the second as the target file name, and thus transfers one file only. Any further parameters are ignored:

> sftp> mput file1 file2
>
> Uploading file1 to /user/TMP/file2
>   file1
>   100%   48     1.9KB/s   00:00

You might want to consider `sftp`'s batch mode to `put` multiple non-globable files.